# Testing for the first weekday of the month in PHP

Tags: php

I'm working on a scheduling function to handle repeating events in an application. One option is 'Every First Weekday' (of the month). I have a function that is working, but I'm afraid I may not be using the most efficient method and was hoping for some input. I'm using PHP 5.5. This is the code I have:

```
function isFirstWeekday($dateObject){
  $dayToTest = $dateObject->format('l');
  $monthToTest = $dateObject->format('F Y');
  $priorDay = clone $dateObject;
  $priorDay->modify('- 1 day');
  $weekdayList = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday");
  //Return false if it's not a weekday
  if (!in_array($dateObject->format('l'), $weekdayList)) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  //Make sure that this weekday is the first of its name in the month
  if ($dateObject->format('Y-m-d') !== date('Y-m-d', strtotime("first $dayToTest of $monthToTest"))) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  //Make sure that the day before was not a weekday in the same month
  if (in_array($priorDay->format('l'), $weekdayList) && $priorDay->format('m') === $dateObject->format('m')) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at it another way.

1) In order for it to be the first weekday, it must be the first, second or third day of the month.

2) If it's the first day, you can directly check if it's a weekday (N = 1-5).

3) If it's the second or third, then in order to be the first weekday, the proceeding days must have NOT been week days. So just check if it's a Monday.

```
function isFirstWeekday($dateObject) {
    switch($dateObject->format('j')) {
        case 1:
            return $dateObject->format('N') <= 5;
        case 2:
        case 3:
            return $dateObject->format('N') == 1;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is much less processor intensive. I didn't realize that conditional returns where an option. I've only been studying PHP for a year and it just never occurred to me. I can't test until I get back to the office on Monday, but after looking at the documentation and thinking it through this looks great. Thank you!

Comment: Why not just this? $date->format('j') < 8

Comment: @MakoBuk the question was to find if the date is the first *weekday* of the month, not the first *week* of the month.

Comment: Of course. The length of the week is 7 days. Then It repeats. The weekday can occur only once in 7 days. There is no reason to check something else.

Comment: @MakoBuk I think you are misunderstanding the question. The OP is not asking to check if it's the first Monday/Tuesday etc. of the month. They want to know if it's the very first weekday (any of Mon-Fri) of the month. As an example, the first weekday of this month would be Tuesday 1st. If you put in Wednesday 2nd, it should return false. Another example, Monday 2nd would be the first weekday in May 2022. If you have interpreted the question differently, I encourage you to post a new answer. The question is rather old but it may benefit someone else.

Comment: @rjdown Aha, ok, then I am misunderstanding the question. The mistake on my side. Sorry